# Calling Close() on Service Proxy blocks after One Way WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple Fire and Forget service operation that works fine and doesn't block. However, when I try to close the service proxy, it will block until the one-way call completes. Is this expected behavior?

**Client Code:**

```
var serviceProxy = new MyServiceProxy();
serviceProxy.OneWayCall();
serviceProxy.Close();  // This blocks until OneWayCall() is finished.
```

**Service:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService {
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void OneWayCall();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService {
   public void OneWayCall() {
      // Stuff and things
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - depending on the binding/configuration your service is using and if you are using sessions in any way. See the below link for information on configurations that lead to blocking:

[WCF Best Practice #5: One-way is not always really one-way](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/gerben/archive/2010/02/01/wcf-best-practice-5-one-way-is-not-always-really-one-way.aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, I found this earlier, and I've been configuring accordingly, but I'm getting other issues... which I may post here again. This is a good post, though.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake; here is what Microsoft has to say about this behavior:

[Clients Blocking with One-Way Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730149%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)